# How to copy a range of non-merge commits to a new branch?

Tags: git

I have a `feature/branch` that at various points merged the `develop` branch into itself during its history. I want to take all the non-merge commits (ie. only the commits that were made originally onto the feature branch) and copy them onto a new branch (based on master) so that I don't have any commits unique to the `develop` branch in the new branch.

I have found a way to list all the commits that I want, but I'm not sure the best way to copy them over to the new branch.  To list the commits I want, I can run this:

```
git log feature/branch ^develop ^master --no-merges
```

How can I get the list (range) of commits output by the above copied onto a new branch?  I think cherry-pick or rebase is the solution, but I haven't been able to figure out the right options to do this after trying a them a few ways. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried git rebase --interactive? Simply create the new branch at the same point than feature/branch and rebase it on master

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell

```
 git log feature/branch ^develop ^master --no-merges --format="%H"
   | ForEach-Object { git cherry-pick $_ }
```

The loop will effectively stop working at the first conflict, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a plumbing-level command for this. For a Unix shell:

```
set -e -u
git rev-list feature/branch ^develop ^master --no-merges \
    | while read rev; do git cherry-pick "$rev"; done
```